# Sequential installation of pumps from the point of view of mechanics

Tags: fluid-mechanics, applied-mechanics

Let's say we have a case of sequential installation of identical pumps in a pipe with a diameter equal to its entire length, water flows in this pipe. Since when the water passes through the first pump, the pump will act on the water and it will receive a certain acceleration, and will receive a constant speed a little further than this pump. Then the question is whether a second pump of the same type will act on the liquid with the same force if the liquid has already acquired the velocity that this pump could give. And can we apply in this case the case of resultant force and the addition of force vectors, if force is a measure of the effect of one body on another, and in our case the question arises whether the second pump will somehow significantly act on water.

Comment: So check out pumping stations on long oil pipelines. Exactly the scenario you propose. Had that as a q at Uni, find the distance between pumps . Consider the delta P.

Comment: Each pump adds pressure. ESPs ( electric submersible) used for oil production, can have more than 50 stages ( pumps). They  typically fit down  4" tubing. Why would you suspect the second pump does not do anything ?

Comment: I mean that when the liquid passes through the first pump, in the future the liquid will have inertia. And the thought stuck in my head about whether the same situation would not happen with the 2 pump, that if a person pushed a car that by itself was already traveling at a speed equal to or greater than the speed of the person pushing it, it turns out he just presses his hands to it, without any significant impact. Or how to try to unwind an already heavily promoted carousel.

Comment: If we are talking about an axial pump, then it spins with its blades and pushes the liquid, but if the liquid has just passed the same pump, provided that the pumps (identical and located, say, 1 meter from each other) and the fluid flow line has not yet stabilized, then it can simply fly between the blades and do not get any impact reaction from the blades of the second pump. Yes, if we put the pump in 500 meters, then it will definitely affect the liquid, because it will lose its inertia about friction and local resistances.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the amount of power each pump is capable of adding to the flow at each stage, this power can manifest itself as an increase of fluid flow, an increase in pressure or an increase in elevation.
Although the pumps are the same they will be operating at different points [Pressure, Temperature, Flowrate] in their characteristics [How they responds to those condition for a given RPM and power input] and therefore their contribution will be different. It could be that your point of operation leads to both pumps providing a similar contribution.
The type of pump also plays in a important role here as different pumps have different characteristics, and in some cases they might not be operable.
I get a feeling you are concerned about the reaction force that the pumps will be experiencing, I hope you understand that all that I have discussed are important factors in this and should be considered.

Comment: Do you get an increase in fluid flow between pumps?

Comment: Mass flow is conserved (doesn't change), I can't comment on volume flow rate without more information but generally for water   which is incompressible I would say it doesn't change. I was able to find this link with some interesting diagrams. www.engineeringtoolbox.com/amp/pumps-parallel-serial-d_636.html